# Why is GCC not allowing me to capture something by reference, while Clang allows it?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, g++, compiler-bug

This is with C++20 (`-std=c++20`), GCC 10.2.0 and Clang 11.1.0.

I have a class `Graph` with a data member `prefix_to_presufs`. In my code, I make a `std::unique_ptr` to a Graph like so:

```
auto gr{std::make_unique<Graph>()};
```

then I try to do this:

```
auto less{[&p2p{gr->prefix_to_presufs}](PreSuf l, PreSuf r) -> bool {
        return p2p[l.suf()].size() < p2p[r.suf()].size();
}};
```

However, GCC gives me this error:

```
filename.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
filename.cc:236:39: error: cannot capture ‘{gr.std::unique_ptr<{anonymous}::Graph, std::default_delete<{anonymous}::Graph> >::operator->()->{anonymous}::Graph::prefix_to_presufs}’ by reference
  236 |  auto less{[&p2p{gr->prefix_to_presufs}](PreSuf l, PreSuf r) -> bool {
      |                                       ^
```

I want to know if what I'm trying to do perhaps is not compliant with the standard and Clang is being unnecessarily permissive, or if this is rather just a GCC bug.

In response to comments below, if I try initializing like this instead: `&p2p = gr->prefix_to_presufs`, my code compiles.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing how `Graph` and `prefix_to_presufs` are declared? The error message is pretty self-explanatory: "*error: cannot capture ‘{prefix_to_presufs}’ by reference*". Do you have the same error with `[&p2p = gr->prefix_to_presufs]`? Can you capture `gr` itself without error? Then you could use `gr->prefix_to_presufs[]` inside the lambda body instead of `p2p[]`

Comment: What happens if you use `=` for the initializer instead? As in `&p2p = gr->prefix_to_presufs`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my code compiles if I use `=`. Does that tell you anything?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Using `=` for initialization indeed makes GCC compile my code. What does that tell you? Is a minimal example still needed?